# How to hash particular column in csv file | linux |

Tags: linux, shell, awk, scripting

I have a scenario

where i want to hash some columns of csv file

how to do that with below data

```
ID|NAME|CITY|AGE
1|AB1|BBC|12
2|AB2|FGD|17
3|AB3|ASD|18
4|AB4|SDF|19
5|AB5|ASC|22
```

The Column name NAME | AGE should get hashed with random values

**like below output**

```
ID|NAME|CITY|AGE
1|68b329da9111314099c7d8ad5cb9c940|BBC|77bAD9da9893er34099c7d8ad5cb9c940
2|69b32fga9893e34099c7d8ad5cb9c940|FGD|68bAD9da989yue34099c7d8ad5cb9c940
3|46b329da9893e3403453d8ad5cb9c940|ASD|60bfgD9da9893e34099c7d8ad5cb9c940
4|50Cd29da9893e34099c7d8ad5cb9c940|SDF|67bAD9da98973e34099c7d8ad5cb9c940
5|67bAD9da9893e34099c7d8ad5cb9c940|ASC|67bAD9da11893e34099c7d8ad5cb9c940
```

When i tested this code below code gives me same value for the column **'NAME'**  it should give  randomized values

```
awk '{
    tmp="echo " $2 " | openssl md5 | cut -f2 -d\" \""
tmp | getline cksum
close(tmp)
$2=cksum
print
}' < sample.csv
```

**output :**

```
 68b329da9893e34099c7d8ad5cb9c940
 68b329da9893e34099c7d8ad5cb9c940
 68b329da9893e34099c7d8ad5cb9c940
 68b329da9893e34099c7d8ad5cb9c940
 68b329da9893e34099c7d8ad5cb9c940
 68b329da9893e34099c7d8ad5cb9c940
```

Comment: there is a difference between md5 values and randomized values. If you want to replace those fields with random string md5 may be an approach but there are faster ways.

Answer (score 2):

You may use it like this:

```
awk 'function hash(s, cmd, hex, line) {
   cmd = "openssl md5 <<< \"" s "\""
   if ( (cmd | getline line) > 0)
      hex = line
   close(cmd)
   return hex
}
BEGIN {
   FS = OFS = "|"
}
NR == 1 {
   print
   next
}
{
   print $1, hash($2), $3, hash($4)
}' file
```

```
ID|NAME|CITY|AGE
1|d44aec35a11ff6fa8a800120dbef1cd7|BBC|2737b49252e2a4c0fe4c342e92b13285
2|157aa4a48373eaf0415ea4229b3d4421|FGD|4d095eeac8ed659b1ce69dcef32ed0dc
3|ba3c08d4a65f1baa1d7220a6802b5710|ASD|cf4278314ef8e4b996e1b798d8eb92cf
4|69be622e1c0d417ceb9b8fb0aa9dc574|SDF|3bb50ff8eeb7ad116724b56a820139fa
5|427872b1ac3a22dc154688ddc2050516|ASC|2fc57d6f63a9ee7e2f21a26fa522e3b6
```

Comment: Very good points Ed (as always). I have edited it accordingly.

Comment: you have a special openssl, I can't find any variant that returns only the sum - mine returns "(stdin)= d44aec35a11ff6fa8a800120dbef1cd7" see: https://ideone.com/KGMWPe

Comment: @Sorin: may be because I am using `2.8.3` on OSX

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify `|` as input and output field separators. Otherwise `$2` is not what you expect, but an empty string.

```
awk -F '|' -v "OFS=|" 'FNR==1 { print; next } {
    tmp="echo " $2 " | openssl md5 | cut -f2 -d\" \""
tmp | getline cksum
close(tmp)
$2=cksum
print
}' sample.csv
```

prints

```
ID|NAME|CITY|AGE
1|d44aec35a11ff6fa8a800120dbef1cd7|BBC|12
2|157aa4a48373eaf0415ea4229b3d4421|FGD|17
3|ba3c08d4a65f1baa1d7220a6802b5710|ASD|18
4|69be622e1c0d417ceb9b8fb0aa9dc574|SDF|19
5|427872b1ac3a22dc154688ddc2050516|ASC|22
```

Comment: how to pass multiple column position in above code you are passing second position $2 => i want to pass $2 and $4 position $2='NAME'  and $4='AGE' this should get md5 value which are randomized

Comment: @jomen40544jmail7.com As you can see in [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60278711/10622916) you can use a function. It was not clear from the question that you don't know how to do the same processing for two fields.

Answer (score 1):

Example using [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) to do the hashing and some awk to rearrange the columns it outputs:

```
$ datamash -t'|' --header-in -f md5 2,4 < input.txt | awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|"; print "ID|NAME|CITY|AGE" } { print $1, $5, $3, $6 }'
ID|NAME|CITY|AGE
1|1109867462b2f0f0470df8386036243c|BBC|c20ad4d76fe97759aa27a0c99bff6710
2|14da3a611e2f8953d76b6fb7866b01d1|FGD|70efdf2ec9b086079795c442636b55fb
3|710a24b9eac0692b1adaabd07726211a|ASD|6f4922f45568161a8cdf4ad2299f6d23
4|c4d15b255ef3c6a89d1fe2e6a26b8eda|SDF|1f0e3dad99908345f7439f8ffabdffc4
5|96b24a28173a75cc3c682e25d3a6bd49|ASC|b6d767d2f8ed5d21a44b0e5886680cb9
```

Note that the MD5 hashes are different in this answer than (At the time of writing) the ones in the others; that's because they use approaches that add a trailing newline to the strings being hashed, producing incorrect results if you want the exact hash:

```
$ echo AB1 | md5sum
d44aec35a11ff6fa8a800120dbef1cd7  -
$ echo -n AB1  | md5sum
1109867462b2f0f0470df8386036243c  -
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a language that has support for md5 included, or at least cache the md5 results (I assume that the city and age have a limited domain, which is smaller than the number of lines).

Perl has support for md5 out of the box:

```
perl -M'Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex)' -F'\|' -le 'if (2..eof) { 
       $F[$_] = md5_hex($F[$_]) for (1,3);
       print join "|",@F 
    } else { print }'
```

online demo: https://ideone.com/xg6cxZ (to my surprise ideone has perl available in bash)

- `Digest::MD5` is a core module, any perl installation should have it
- `-M'Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex)'` - this loads the md5_hex function
- `-l` handle line endings
- `-F'\|'` - autosplit fields on | (this implies -a and -n)
- `2..eof` - range operator (or flip-flop as some want to call it) - true between line 2 and end of the file
- `$F[$_] = md5_hex($F[$_])` - replace field $_ with it's md5 sum
- `for (1,3)` - [statement modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers) runs the statement for 1 and 3 aliasing $_ to them
- `print join "|",@F` - print the modified fields
- `else { print }` - this hanldes the header

**Note about speed**: on my machine this processes ~100,000 lines in about 100 ms, compared with an awk variant of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60278711/939457) that does 5000 lines in ~1 minute 14 seconds (i wasn't patient enough to wait for 100,000 lines)

```
time perl -M'Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex)' -F'\|' -le 'if (2..eof) { $F[$_] = md5_hex($F[$_]) for (1,3);print join "|",@F } else { print }' <sample2.txt > out4.txt 

real    0m0.121s
user    0m0.118s
sys 0m0.003s
$ time awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' -i md5.awk '{ print $1,md5($2),$3,md5($4) }' <(head -5000 sample2.txt) >out2.txt

real    1m14.205s
user    0m50.405s
sys 0m35.340s
```

md5.awk defines the md5 function as such:

```
$ cat md5.awk 
function md5(str, cmd, l, hex) {
    cmd= "/bin/echo -n "str" | openssl md5 -r"
    if ( ( cmd | getline l) > 0 ) 
        hex = substr(l,0,32)
    close(cmd)
    return hex
}
```

- I'm using `/bin/echo` because there are some variants of shell where echo doesn't have -n
- I'm using `-n` mostly because I want to be able to compare the results with the perl results
- `substr(l,0,32)` - on my machine `openssl md5` doesn't return just the sum, it has also the file name - see: https://ideone.com/KGMWPe - substr gets only the relevant part
- I'm using a separate file because it seems much cleaner, and because I can switch between function implementations fairly easy

As I was saying in the beginning, if you really want to use awk, at least cache the result of the `openssl` tool.

```
$ cat md5memo.awk 
function md5(str, cmd, l, hex) {
    if (cache[str]) 
        return cache[str]
    cmd= "/bin/echo -n "str" | openssl md5 -r"
    if ( ( cmd | getline l) > 0 ) 
        hex = substr(l,0,32)
    close(cmd)
    cache[str] = hex
    return hex
}
```

With the above caching, the results improve dramatically:

```
$ time awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' -i md5memo.awk '{ print $1,md5($2),$3,md5($4) }' <(head -5000 sample2.txt) >outmemo.txt

real    0m0.192s
user    0m0.141s
sys 0m0.085s
[savuso@localhost hash]$ time awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' -i md5memo.awk '{ print $1,md5($2),$3,md5($4) }' <sample2.txt >outmemof.txt

real    0m0.281s
user    0m0.222s
sys 0m0.088s
```

**however your mileage my vary**: sample2.txt has 100000 lines, with 5 different values for $2 and 40 different values for $4. Real life data may vary!

Note: I just realized that my awk implementation doesn't handle headers, but you can get that from the other answers